# Open Shortcut in new browser window

Tags: theming

drupal 7.61 adminimal_menu
I need to have two shortcuts on the shortcut bar open in a new browser window instead of the default same window without having to "right-click".
Users are sometimes forgetting to right click[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cann't set/configure it from admin panel (admin/config/user-interface/shortcut/link) because there are no option in Shortcut module configuration.

Now you can use any one of following modules:
https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes
https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink

or following jQuery script to your page.tpl.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id').children(":first").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```